# Background of nav bar transparent only for background of body

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the nav bar transparent so that the transparency is only used for the background color? For example, I have a fixed navbar on top and as I scroll down I only want the navbar to have the colors of the current background color of my container so that if I scroll down I don't see the text? (I'm using a gradiant and not a fixed color...)

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Could your elaborate a bit? Do I need to use javascript to achieve that or how can I find out how to do it?

Comment: Yes, its possible. If I understood your question right, below is an example.
https://www.softway.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript you can add an scroll event listener and then check how far the user has scrolled. So if they've scrolled past a certain point make the background transparent. Otherwise, keep it as a gradient.

```js
checkNavBackground = () => {
  var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0]
  
  var threshold = 400

  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

  if (scrollTop > threshold){
    nav.style.background= 'transparent'
  } else {
    nav.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow)'
  }

}

document.addEventListener('scroll', checkNavBackground)
```

```css
.navbar {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
 
 .body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='body'>
<div class='navbar'>
  Here is a div with text
</div>
</div>
```